# Conformal field theory on the plane mapped to a cylinder mapped to a plane

Tags: coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory

Consider a conformal field theory on a Euclidean plane with coordinate $ w = x^{0} + ix^{1}$, with the time coordinate $x^{0}$ and the space coordinate $x^1$.

---

**Map from plane to cylinder via compactification:**

We compactify the space coordinate $x^1$ to obtain a cylinder with the identification

$$x^{1} \sim x^{1} + \ell,$$

where $\ell$ is the circumference of the cylinder.

---

**Map from cylinder to plane via exponentiation:**

We next use the coordinate transformation $z = e^{x^{0}}\cdot{e^{ix^{1}}}$ to map the cylinder onto the plane, so that the time coordinate on the cylinder becomes the radial coordinate on the plane and the space coordinate on the cylinder becomes the angular coordinate on the plane.

When we quantize the conformal field theory on the complex plane with coordinate $z$, time ordering becomes radial ordering and the quantization procedure is called radial quantization.

---

**Why do we compactify the space coordinate $x^1$ to form the cylinder?**

**What is the motivation behind this series of mappings in the study of conformal field theory?**

Comment: It's more or less the same reason people use the Cayley transform to map the real line onto the circle: it's just a matter of convenience in using compact sets rather than infinite lines. Also, transformations like diffeomorphisms and the like have a nicer form on the circle and so do the rest of the conformal transformations.

Comment: Also, note that these maps are conformal (they preserve angles), so you can use them safely when you study CFT. This is why those transformations are used specifically in CFT and not in arbitrary QFT.

Comment: There is no intrinsic reason for compactifying - what we are doing there is studying the CFT on $S_R^1$ which is by definition periodic. One then hopes to reproduce the physics on ${\mathbb R}$ by taking $R \to \infty$ - this last step is of course not trivial since there are additional modes on the boundaries of ${\mathbb R}$ which are not in $S^1$. The last step is also not necessary - one could simply be interested in studying CFT on circles (for example in string theory, this is precisely the case).

Answer (score 1):

The physics of compactifing the space direction is when one consider a physical system with periodic boundary condition. For example, 1d quantum spin chain on the circle. The map from cylinder to plane is also useful when we compactify the time direction, corresponding to thermal theory of CFT.  This mapping relate the correlators in thermal theory to the correlators in zero temperature theory. So it's convenient.

Comment: I understand what is meant by "periodic boundary contdition" it means something which repeats infinity "along one dimension" like a tilable image (x or y dimensions), or a looped animation (temporal dimension)